# Oracle SQL -- Case Insensitive Primary Key

Tags: oracle11g, primary-key, case-insensitive

I am experiencing the following issue under Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production.

The following code creates a unique index on the primary key (ID) [VARCHAR2] of table USER1. It works properly.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX USER1_PK ON USER1
(ID)
COMPUTE STATISTICS
LOGGING
TABLESPACE ACT_INDX
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          128K
            NEXT             128K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );


ALTER TABLE USER1 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT USER1_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (ID)
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

An emergent requirement wants the primary key (ID) values to be case insensitive (e.g. aa-aaa-aaaa, AA-AAA-AAAA, aa-AAA-aaa, etc. are to be considered the same).

However, when I change the code by changing (ID) to UPPER((ID)) below, Oracle throws a SQL Error "ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint" when creating the constraint. How must my code be modified to provide the functionality required without throwing an error. I can't change the table schema. Thank you.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX USER1_PK ON USER1
UPPER((ID))
COMPUTE STATISTICS
LOGGING
TABLESPACE ACT_INDX
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          128K
            NEXT             128K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );


ALTER TABLE USER1 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT USER1_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (ID)
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Comment: You may have more joy with getting an answer to this question at dba.stackexchage.com

Answer (score 0):

Virtual columns are a handy (11g+) feature for these cases.

```
alter table user1
add (
    uppercase_id generated always as (upper(id))
);
```

And now you're all set up for success.

```
alter table user1
add constraint user1_pk
    primary key (uppercase_id)
    COMPUTE STATISTICS
    TABLESPACE ACT_INDX
;
```